# how to change dynamic the value of a array field when the field is empty

Tags: javascript, logic

here is the code I have written:

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i].mkp == ' ') {
        //the first time that a empty field happen
        //the array position is filled with "FRANQUIAS"
        result[i].mkp = "FRANQUIAS";
    }
    if (result[i].mkp == ' ') {
        //the second time that a empty field happen
        //the array position is filled with "TELEVENDAS"
        result[i].mkp = "TELEVENDAS";
    }
    if (result[i].mkp == ' ') {
        //the third time that a empty field happen
        //the array position is filled with "OCC"
        result[i].mkp = "OCC";
    }
}
```

But I can't figure it out by myself how could I achieve my purpose of changing the empty fields to these three fields. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep an additional counter variable which increments when empty filed occurs.

```
// variable for keeping track of empty field
let c = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // chek value or couter in addition to your condition
    if (c === 0 && result[i].mkp == ' ') {
        //the first time that a empty field happen
        //the array position is filled with "FRANQUIAS"
        result[i].mkp = "FRANQUIAS";
        // increment counter value whenever empty field occurs
        c++;
    }
    else if (c === 1 && result[i].mkp == ' ') {
        //the second time that a empty field happen
        //the array position is filled with "TELEVENDAS"
        result[i].mkp = "TELEVENDAS";
        c++;
    }
    else if (c === 2 && result[i].mkp == ' ') {
        //the third time that a empty field happen
        //the array position is filled with "OCC"
        result[i].mkp = "OCC";
        c++;
    }
}
```

---

You can even simplify the code by using an array which contains those values.

```
// variable for keeping track of empty field
let c = 0;
// array which contains the value
const val = [ 'FRANQUIAS', 'TELEVENDAS', 'OCC'];

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
     // check counter is less than 3(update if there is more possibility or use c < val.length)
     // and check value is empty
     if (c < 3 && result[i].mkp == ' ') {
        // update value with corresponding value in array 
        // and increment, where `c++` returns current value and increments 
        result[i].mkp = val[c++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I only receive "FRANQUIAS". This is the code: http://prntscr.com/n33bv8

Comment: @MateusFernando : can u share `result` array data before the loop

Comment: Sorry, I put the var C inside the for, so it always be 0. I changed and it's working! Thank you.

Comment: @MateusFernando, Pranav has given the correct code. You have made a slight error. I think Pranav too might have overlooked that in the picture you have given. You are initializing `c = 0` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: That's that I said...no?

Comment: @Rai thanks mate... I didn't noticed that in his code :)

Comment: @MateusFernando, you did tell the same. Just that both of us sent out the comments at almost the same time. No offence meant buddy.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) for your replacement values, then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```js
const input = [{ mkp: 'not empty' }, { mkp: ' ' }, { mkp: ' ' }, { mkp: 'something' }, { mkp: ' ' }, { mkp: 'something else' }];

const replacement = (function* () {
  yield 'FRANQUIAS';
  yield 'TELEVENDAS';
  yield 'OCC';
})();

const result = input.map(o => ({ ...o, mkp: o.mkp === ' ' ? replacement.next().value : o.mkp }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: with spread syntax : `input.map(o =>  ({ ...o, mkp: o.mkp === ' ' ? replacement.next().value : o.mkp }));`

Comment: ah, very nice.  answer updated, thanks @PranavCBalan!

Comment: Now it looks better than before :)